# JOLT: How to group the JSON attribute starting with common name and make them array

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

Can someone help in grouping the JSON attributes starting with same name. And also if the field values are NULL ignore them

**Input**

```
{
  "Project": "ABC",
  "Project Code": "ABC",
  "Image 1 URL": null,
  "Image 1 Description": null,
  "Image 2 URL": "https://test.com",
  "Image 2 Description": "description 2",
  "Image 3 URL": null,
  "Image 3 Description": null,
  "Image 4 URL": "https://test.com",
  "Image 4 Description": "description 4"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
   "projectName":"ABC",
   "projectCode":"ABC",
   "media":{
      "images":[
         {
            "name":"Image 2",
            "url":"https://test.com",
            "description":"description 2"
         },
         {
            "name":"Image 4",
            "url":"https://test.com",
            "description":"description 4"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  { // group by substrings within the key literals
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Project": "projectName",
      "P* *": "p&(0,1)&(0,2)",
      "I* * *": "I&(0,1) &(0,2).&(0,3)"
    }
  },
  { // remove attributes URL & Description with NULL values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  { // remove remaining objects with no content
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "I*": {
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert keys of the attributes to lower-case
    // while adding the attribute "name"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "I*": {
        "$": "&1.name",
        "URL": "&1.url",
        "D*": "&1.d&(0,1)" // &(0,1) : extract the 1st asterisk replacement from the current(0th) level -> "escription"
      }
    }
  },
  { // nest the Image attributes within media object and images array  
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "I*": {
        "*": "media.images[#2].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the newly generated NULL values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]